# Managing fine-grained access to credentials on Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

I am trying to limit access to the secrets/certificates so that only certain users can view/access some of them.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: It is impossible currently.

Answer (score 0):

> limit access to the secrets/certificates so that only certain users can view/access some of them.

In short, it's impossible.

You can limit only certain user to access all the secrets or certificates, other than access some of the secrets.

Simply find the Azure Key Vault in the Azure portal UI, click `Access policies` under settings, and add a new access policy. You **can define fine-grained permissions for accessing Key, Secret, and Certificates** (which Azure Key Vault can also store, by the way). However, when you allow some user to access your key vault secret, they will access all the secrets in azure Key vault.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blog.couchbase.com/azure-key-vault-credentials/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting a proxy in place that enforces fine grained access controls and only allow the proxy to directly access Azure Key Vault. We do this for Azure Key Vault, AWS KMS, and AWS CloudHSM. [This](https://garantir.io/garasign/) is the proxy we use, although if your needs are simple enough you may be able to write it yourself.